# How to use regex to identify posts by different people on a forum?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Im trying to use regex to identify posts by different students.

The posts are always of the form:

> "U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out
>   http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. \n U39501492\n That's a
>   cool website. \n U5235098\n I'll have a look too"

1. So the student id can be of 7-8 numbers long.
2. The students can post
   anything. words, numbers, punctuation etc.
3. We don't know how many
   posts there will be by how many people.

How can I use regex to create a list where the elements are the posts of each student in the sequence that it's posted.

The students can post anything, so Im using [\s\S]+ to capture that. My attempt was: `re.findall('(U\d+\n[\s\S]+?)',text)`. However this only returns the ID of the students not their texts: `['U3951583\n ', 'U39501492\n ', 'U5235098\n ']`

How can I use regex match in this case?

Comment: What is the exact Python version?

Comment: Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)

Comment: It could be that the non-greedy match pattern you have there is not greedy enough.

Comment: Please check the answers below and let know if anything works for you, or if you need more help / clarifications.

Answer (score 4):

You may use `re.findall` approach:

```
import re
txt = "U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. \n U39501492\n That's a cool website. \n U5235098\n I'll have a look too"
print(re.findall(r'\bU\d{7,8}\b.*?(?=\bU\d{7,8}\b|\Z)', txt, re.S))
# => ["U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. \n ", "U39501492\n That's a cool website. \n ", "U5235098\n I'll have a look too"]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Cimnz2)

A variation to get both name and content separately:

```
for name, content in re.findall(r'\b(U\d{7,8})\b(.*?)(?=\bU\d{7,8}\b|\Z)', txt, re.S):
    print("{}:{}".format(name.strip(), content.strip()))
```

Output:

```
U3951583:Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website.
U39501492:That's a cool website.
U5235098:I'll have a look too
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/iPpmq4)

The regex used is

```
\b(U\d{7,8})\b(.*?)(?=\bU\d{7,8}\b|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OW4j62/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (no letter/digit/`_` can appear immediately to the left of the current location)
- `(U\d{7,8})` - Group 1: `U` and 7 or 8 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\bU\d{7,8}\b|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that requires the pattern described above (a name pattern) immediately to the right of the current location or (`|`) end of string (`\Z`).

**Python 3.7+**

In the latest Python versions, you may `re.split` with a pattern that matches an empty string:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = "U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. 
\n U39501492\n That's a cool website. \n U5235098\n I'll have a look too"
>>> print(re.split(r'(?!^)(?=\bU\d{7,8}\b)', txt))
["U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. \n ", "U3
9501492\n That's a cool website. \n ", "U5235098\n I'll have a look too"]
```

So, if you do not need to get the names and contents separately this might be a simpler approach.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM All explanations have been added.

Comment: Could you please explain (?!^) in the re.split example?

Comment: @SarahHolder `(?!^)` = *not at the start of the string*

Answer (score 1):

You could match the U and the 7-8 digits followed by the lines that do not start with that same pattern.

```
\bU\d{7,8}(?:\r?\n(?![ ]*U\d{7}).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\bU\d{7,8}` Word boundary, match U followed by 7 - 8 digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `[ ]*\bU\d{7}` Match 0+ times a space followed by word boundary, U and 7 digits
  - `).*` Close negative lookahead and match any char 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times to match all following lines

For example

```
import re

s = "U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. \n U39501492\n That's a cool website. \n U5235098\n I'll have a look too"
regex = r"\bU\d{7,8}(?:\r?\n(?![ ]*U\d{7}).*)*"

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Result

```
["U3951583\n Hi there my name is Harry. Check out http://www.harryresume.com. That's my website. ", "U39501492\n That's a cool website. ", "U5235098\n I'll have a look too"]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zeUh8t/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GPyunn)

Answer (score 0):

Try use this regex:

```
\d{7,8}
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zkFRfx/1)

Good Luck!